# ExpandableListViewGroupPosition?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have implemented `ExpandedListView`. I have 2 questions for that

1. When I expand and scroll child item ,the group header also scroll ,is any way to keep that group header at top always even we scrolling child item list ?
2. Is any way to fit ExpandableListView (before child items comes) to phone screen , right now in bottom lot of blank space  ?

Comment: did you found any solution for 1st problem?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

no there is no why that you can fix the group view, if you want to fix group i would suggest you to make four list view on screen. where in a Linearlayout make 4 textview and 4 listview placed alternately so that they are fixed and if there is no child inside you can write some appropriate message saying there is nothing to display.

And i guess it solve your second question as well ?

Answer (score 0):

**1. When I expand and scroll child item ,the group header also scroll ,is any way to keep that group header at top always even we scrolling child item list ?**

**No**, ExpandableListView's Header's (Parent) and Childs are connected to eachother You can not independently scroll the Child views besides scrolling parent views.

**2. Is any way to fit ExpandableListView (before child items comes) to phone screen , right now in bottom lot of blank space ?**

You can fit the `ExpandableListView` by setting its height and width to fixed but it will be always affected as and when you will add some data into it. Till then you can not fit it into the screen.